# Use magnificPopup with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have two photos, both have the class "foto". Under each photo i added a button which allows me to delete the photo.

However, i can still open the photo in the galery after removing a photo from the DOM, instead of 1 of 1 photos like expected, i still have 1 of 2 at the bottom right and i can still see the deleted photo within magnificPopup's galery. Is it still in the cache?

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        $('.foto').magnificPopup
        (
            {
                type: 'image',
                closeOnContentClick: false,
                closeBtnInside: false,
                mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
                image: 
                {
                    verticalFit: true,
                    titleSrc: function(item) 
                    {
                        return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="'+item.el.attr('data-source')+'" target="_blank">image source</a>';
                    }
                },
                gallery: 
                { 
                    enabled: true 
                },
                zoom: 
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    duration: 300, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
                    opener: function(element) 
                    {
                        return element.find('img');
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Is magnificPopup not compatible with dynamic elements? Is there a way to reinitialize the function without reloading the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I added the event listeners into a function, then i just call this function anytime when i need to reinitialise it.

```
function init_magnificPopup()
{
        $('.foto').magnificPopup
        (
            {
                type: 'image',
                closeOnContentClick: false,
                closeBtnInside: false,
                mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
                image: 
                {
                    verticalFit: true,
                    titleSrc: function(item) 
                    {
                        return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="'+item.el.attr('data-source')+'" target="_blank">image source</a>';
                    }
                },
                gallery: 
                { 
                    enabled: true 
                },
                zoom: 
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    duration: 300, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
                    opener: function(element) 
                    {
                        return element.find('img');
                    }
                }
            }
        );
}

$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        init_magnificPopup();
    }
);
```

So i just call `init_magnificPopup()` at the end of my delete function. That works :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this ;)

```
function initMagnificPopup(){
    $('.foto').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true,
            titleSrc: function(item) {
                return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="'+item.el.attr('data-source')+'" target="_blank">image source</a>';
           }
        },
        gallery: { 
           enabled: true 
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
            opener: function(element) {
                return element.find('img');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    initMagnificPopup();
    /* add call this function whenever you delete an image. */
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  i upvote yours even though i just figured out the same solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this with dynamic elements:

`$(document).on('click', '.foto', function () {
    $(this).magnificPopup({....});
});`